# Why current UTC time on my local server and UTC time on my hosting server are different?

Tags: php, timezone

I printed below code on my local server and on my hosting server but seems both displaying diff. time for UTC timezone. Please explain me.

```
echo print gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z"); 

//Output on LOCAL SERVER: 2014-09-12T08:02:49Z1UTC //It is the correct one 

//Output on HOSTING SERVER: 2014-09-12T06:51:39Z1
```

Comment: (a) what time did you run the commands at, and (b) is the clock set wrong on one of the servers? (Do you have shell access on each of them? Are they unix servers? What do they say if you just use the "date" command on the command line?)

Comment: run `date -u` command in console on both systems consecutively and post the output here

Comment: It's give me "Fri Sep 12 07:38:10 UTC 2014" on hosting server.

Comment: It'd be really helpful if you could tell us (a) what actual time you ran the `date` command at, and (b) the results for both servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution. Actually my server time is not sync with world clock. I needed to install NTP (Network Time Protocol) service on my server. I have installed on CentOs using below link.

Check this out: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-ntp-to-synchronize-server-clock/