# UTC time different for local and server

Tags: java, datetime

I am saving time with other data to show in my app . I am storing the time in utc in db . Now when i run the program locally it works fine but when i run code on server the time is different from utc . My code to get utc timestamp is

```
private Timestamp getUTCTimestamp() throws ParseException
{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATEFORMAT);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    String utcTime = sdf.format(new Date());

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATEFORMAT);     
    Timestamp dateToReturn = new Timestamp(((Date)dateFormat.parse(utcTime)).getTime());

    return dateToReturn;
}
```

It returns acurate utc time but when i run it on server it doesn't give the utc time e.g i ran the program locally and it gave me "2016-04-17 20:58:55" which was right and then after 10 mins i ran the code on server and it saved the time "2016-04-17 16:02:46" which was different .My server location is in netharlands. I don't understand , shouldn't the utc time be same everywhere??

Comment: Please provide the actual and expected output of this code.

Comment: Shouldn't dateFormat also be set to UTC timezone?

Comment: @any turner i have added a short result in question

Comment: no i don't think so my utcTime variable already has the utc time so i don't need to set again

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to save current time on DB, it is much better to save with *NOW()* function of MySQL to make sure wherever the code runs, as far as the DB is the same, NOW() values will be consistent and you don't need to create time objects and lines of code to handle current time on java side.

see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

Comment: I meant that he does not need to struggle with different time settings of different machines.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you formatting and then parsing the formatted string? Just use:

```
private Timestamp getUTCTimestamp() throws ParseException
{  
    return new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
}
```

As to the issue you're seeing, I think @Stanislav Palatnik's comment is correct. You need to set the timezone on your format that is parsing the time string. Or just use the same format for formatting and parsing.. but again, why do you even need to go through that work?

Comment: this way obviously doesn't return utc time , i m using format because i found this is the only way to set utc time.

Comment: That way does return UTC time. Check the docs of Date https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using old troublesome classes that are now outmoded. Avoid using SimpleDateFormat, java.util.Date/.Calendar and such, and minimize use of java.sql types.

Among their many problems is the behavior of `toString` method, applying a default time zone while generating the string. This confuses debugging efforts.

## java.time

The java.time classes supplant the old date-time classes. Built into Java 8 and later, available as back-ports to Java 6 & 7 and to Android.

Do your business logic in java.time. Use java.sql only until JDBC drivers are updated to handle java.time types directly.

Define your column as something close to the SQL standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. Not "WITHOUT".

An `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

Convert to java.sql.Timestamp for storage in database.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from( instant );
```

Going the direction.

```
Instant instant = ts.toInstant();
```

The `toString` methods in java.time classes do not apply mysterious time zones when generating the textual representation of their date-time value. And they use standard ISO 8601 formats to further clarity.

So we go in and out of the database 
all in UTC, no time zones, very simple, very clear.

When you need a wall-clock value such as far presentation to user, Apple a time zone to the instant to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Covered in detail in many other pages in Stack Overflow.

Your servers should be assigned a time zone of UTC (or Iceland). But never depend on that. Using the approach shown above makes the server’s time zone irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

No answer could have helped me because i found the reason and it had nothing to do with the code . I ran this command Date -u on putty and realized that the time isn't synchronized with utc and i don't know why . This post helped me in getting to this reason. I haven't tried the solution so if someone has a better solution feel free to tell me :) This is the 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803590/why-current-utc-time-on-my-local-server-and-utc-time-on-my-hosting-server-are-di)